# remove IBOutlets from Network func

Tags: swift

I have a weather application and there is a function that checks the availability of the Internet

I want to remove everything from there that is connected with IBOutlets and VC, but I don't know how, I assume that through the closure, could you tell me please how I can do it, I'm still a beginner

```
@IBOutlet weak var brickScroll: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var noticeNetwork: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var brickImageView: UIImageView!

func monitorNetwork() {
        let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            if path.status == .satisfied {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.managerStartUpdatingLocation()  
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.brickImageView.image = UIImage(named: "empty")
                    self.noticeNetwork.isHidden = false
                    self.brickScroll.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                }
            }
        }
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Network")
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
```

Comment: This could work I think but could you be more clear about your goal? Additionally, maybe hiding items is not the best approach? Apple Human Interface Guidelines tend to encourage that you notify the user somehow if some parts of the app's functionality are not available (i.e. Alert: Can't access mobile network for weather data).

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your purpose is to move this ability out of a view controller into some class of its own. (?)  In that case, you can let the caller decide what to do with UI elements.

```
func monitorNetwork(unsatisfied: @escaping ()->()) {
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
        if path.status == .satisfied {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.managerStartUpdatingLocation()  
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                unsatisfied()
            }
        }
    }
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Network")
    monitor.start(queue: queue)
}
```

Comment: yes, I need to remove this function from the VC, as I have heard that it is bad when functions with network are in vc, thank you!

Comment: Phillip's answer looks like what you need. Do you understand what it's doing? you'd now call the monitorNetwork() function, and pass it the code that you want to be executed if the path is not returned as .satisfied. The function will set up the network path monitor and ask it to execute your code when it gets back a network update with a status != .satisfied. The code you pass in would update your UI as needed.

Comment: Phillip, shouldn't the unsatisfied closure be marked as `@escaping`?

Comment: @DuncanC  Good point.